# Trying to customize the order review table in the Woocommerce checkout page with a custom layout. Can someone review my code please?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

In order review section from Woocommerce checkout page, I am attempting to incorporate the following design:

[image]

This is the code snippet I have tried using:

```
<?php
/**
 * Review order table
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.8.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>

<!-- Custom Order Review Section Layout Starts here -->
<div class="co_review_section shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
        <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents' );

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                ?>
                <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                    <div class="product-name co_product_name">
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times;&nbsp;%s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                        <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-total co_product_total">
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents' );
        ?>
    <tfoot>

        <div class="cart-subtotal co_product_subtotal">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'ecw-checkout-widget' ); ?></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?></td>
        </div>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
            <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
                <td><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>

            <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee ) : ?>
            <tr class="fee">
                <th><?php echo esc_html( $fee->name ); ?></th>
                <td><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ( wc_tax_enabled() && ! WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) : ?>
            <?php if ( 'itemized' === get_option( 'woocommerce_tax_total_display' ) ) : ?>
                <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_tax_totals() as $code => $tax ) : // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.OverrideProhibited ?>
                    <tr class="tax-rate tax-rate-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                        <th><?php echo esc_html( $tax->label ); ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo wp_kses_post( $tax->formatted_amount ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <tr class="tax-total">
                    <th><?php echo esc_html( WC()->countries->tax_or_vat() ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php wc_cart_totals_taxes_total_html(); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total' ); ?>

        <tr class="order-total">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'ecw-checkout-widget' ); ?></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total' ); ?>

    </tfoot>
</div>
```

But I got stuck. Now, this led to this structure:

[image]

which has been messed up in terms of layout.

I've used [Change Quantity on Checkout for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-quantity-on-checkout-for-woocommerce/) plugin, to get the quantity button & delete button, to appear inside the order table. But this is not helping out too as you could see.

Now I am badly stuck! Please help me correct the code.

P.S - The Product thumb image, Product Name & Variants, Price & Delete icon needs to be placed in 1/3 + 2/3 + 1 /3 layout.

Thanks in advance.